# How to search a video using youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-api

1.how to get the number of video likes with youtube api ( python )
2.How to get the comments of all search results with youtube api( python )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using youtube api, how to get the list of likes of a search results in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736808/using-youtube-api-how-to-get-the-list-of-likes-of-a-search-results-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on the official Google dev Site:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser


# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "REPLACE_ME"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
      channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
      playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

  print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
  print "Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n"
  print "Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Google")
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  try:
    youtube_search(args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python

Comment: I also want to find the number of video likes and the comments posted for the search results. If you know about this please help

Answer (score 0):

1) First get the search result. Search results will not have likes and comments count
2) for each search result, fire an api request to get video info

Below code will give you the like count and comment count for each video in the search results.

```
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      payload = {'id': search_result["id"]["videoId"], 'part': 'statistics', 'key': DEVELOPER_KEY}
      l = requests.Session().get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', params=payload)    
      resp_dict = json.loads(l.text)
      print "commentCount: ",resp_dict['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']
      print "likeCount: ",resp_dict['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
```