# Using youtube api, how to get the list of likes of a search results in python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api

For eg: if search the keyword "Indian Cricket team"..search results contains a set of videos. I want to get the like got for each videos.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over search results to get [videoIds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#id.videoId) together, then use [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call to get [likes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.likeCount) of videos.

You can check [Python samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python) for examples.